# Cloudflare certificate not being used in https connection

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, wildcard-subdomain

I am using cloudflare to proxy requests to my server and within my server I have added support for subdomains. The issue is that my server only has an ssl certificate issued to the root domain, but the cloudflare certificate has support for wildcards. Whenever there is a request to the root domain the ssl certificate from cloudflare is used but when I try to access a subdomain my server's certificate is used and I get a nasty the domain is insecure error. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? There is a CNAME record within cloudflare which has the `*` name as an alias to my domain.

Comment: it seems that you have TLS SNI ([Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) problem. I don't use CloudFlare as proxy myself, but you should search at CloudFlare about configuring of Server Name Indication. The problem can depend on which SSL certificate you use. See [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203274000-Does-CloudFlare-s-free-Universal-SSL-have-limitations-) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Free CloudFlare account, only browsers with SNI support work. This is so CloudFlare doesn't need to assign an IP for every free client; using a Pro account you can have support for legacy browsers which don't support SNI.